# FQDN of EC2 instance from AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fqdn

How Can I determine the FQDN of my Ec2 instance from AWS Ec2 console?

Regards,
Sakshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breakdown of FQDN os as follows `[hostname].[domain].[tld].`.

there are 2 ways to find this.

- using console under `instance summary.`
- using [ec2 metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). run the following command to from within your ec2 instance.

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname`

[list of metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Could you please share the screenshot of console under instance summary Where we can find this . Is this "Public DNS (IPV4) field ?

Comment: Yes it is  `Public DNS (IPV4) field `. if the answer was helpful anupvote/acceptance as answer to your problem will be appreciated so that it help others in the future

Comment: Your response was  very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can get the FQDN of any IP address using standard tools nslookup or dig. They are also shown in the AWS Console. You can also use a free service like xip.io to make up hostnames pointing to any IP address, for example, 203.0.113.55 could be [www.mysite.203.0.113.55.xip.io](http://www.mysite.203.0.113.55.xip.io). No configuration needed, you just create a hostname and as long as your IP appears immediately to the left of "xip.io" this just works.